# while loading the page, i need to display the maximum value of the column(in table ) in a label box

Tags: c#, asp.net

while loading the page in asp dot net using c sharp, i need to display the maximum value of the column(in table ) in a label boxs always

Select max(refno+1) from master.i am new in asp pls,help

Comment: is this HTML table? WebControl table?

Comment: Sorry, I think I did not get question correctly. Could you please rephrase?
A picture perhaps ?

Comment: Can you provide some description of your data ?

Comment: SqlDatareader cmd =new SqlDatareader("select max(refno+1) from master"con);DataSet ds=new DataSet();cmd.fill(ds);label.text=ds;

Comment: My code attached here but its not wrking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it correctly, your code

```
SqlDatareader cmd =new SqlDatareader("select max(refno+1) from master"con);
DataSet ds=new DataSet();
cmd.fill(ds);
label.text=ds;
```

Last line should be then

```
 label.text=ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count;
```

Comment: You might double check; I don't think the count of columns in the returned results is quite what the label needs to be set to

Comment: Glad, I was able to help

Comment: DS.Tables[0].Columns.Count.ToString() .. But always  showing value 1

Comment: That is correct, number of columns same as a number of the fields you are selecting in your statement. In your case "select max(refno+1) from master" there is only one field being selected, so number of columns (and in this particular select - number of rows) always will be 1.